# What is Brassisca Pink?

Tags: houseplants, ornamental-plant

Yesterday I purchased a plant from Ikea Egypt, called Brassisca Pink. I have tried to search Google and wikipedia for any details about this plant, but I could not able to find anything. I have transferred it into the permanent jar and shot it the following photo:
[image]

I need to know any documented information or data about this plant, including the scientific name, how to cultivate it, does it need strong sun light?, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is supposed to have pink flowers, as the name suggests, then it could be this plant: https://worldofsucculents.com/carpobrotus-acinaciformis-hottentot-fig-sour-fig-giant-pigface-ice-plant/

Or one of many sedum types: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedum_reflexum

Comment: Initially, I realized that it belongs to Sedum, but all Sedums that I have seen before are herbs without solid stem such as shown in the image.